# Getting error while using Login Controls?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, login-control

I Droped a **'Login'** login control in my page and then clicked on the Administrator website.
There i clicked on security and got the following error

***There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 
The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.***

Please  tell me why this error occurring and what i have to do solve this error?

My web.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=jaijinendera"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What you want to know.. ?? every thing tells the message..

Comment: Why it is unable to connect to sql-sever-database

Comment: have you created connection string in the web.config file

Comment: have you checked it... ?? is connctionstring is there?? if no then create connectionstring

Comment: Please google on how to create connectionstring.. that will help you